# How do I set the destination table for a query in BigQuqery Ruby API?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a method for BigQuery API that allows you to set the destination table for a query? I found one in the REST API but not for programming languages like ruby.

If there is an example for other languages.. maybe I can try to do the same in ruby

Comment: https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-bigquery/v0.23.0/google/cloud/bigquery/queryjob?method=destination-instance

Comment: Thanks to that link, I now know how they treat "jobs" for bigquery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@mikhailberlyant found it.

[Bigquery documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-bigquery/v0.23.0/google/cloud/bigquery/queryjob?method=destination-instance)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `destination table` via the API. Either one of these example snippets should be easy to port to the [Ruby](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-bigquery/v0.23.0/google/cloud/bigquery/queryjob?method=destination-instance) client, and be enough to get you going:

**Java**

```
JobConfiguration jobConfiguration = newBuilder("select * from..)
                    .setAllowLargeResults(true)
                    .setUseLegacySql(false)
                    .setDryRun(dryRun)
                    .setDestinationTable(TableId.of("projectId", "dataset", "table"))
                    .setCreateDisposition(CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                    .setWriteDisposition(WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                    .setPriority(BATCH)
                    .build();
```

**Python**

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client()
query = """\
SELECT firstname + ' ' + last_name AS full_name,
       FLOOR(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), birth_date) / 365) AS age
 FROM dataset_name.persons
"""
dataset = client.dataset('dataset_name')
table = dataset.table(name='person_ages')
job = client.run_async_query('fullname-age-query-job', query)
job.destination = table
job.write_disposition= 'truncate'
job.begin()
```

Answer (score 1):

didn't know if this is exactly what you were asking - but looks like it is :o)

[Ruby API Reference Documentation](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/#/docs/google-cloud-bigquery/v0.23.0/google/cloud/bigquery) for the Google BigQuery API Client Library.

You can see more for all supported clients in [BigQuery Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries)

Answer (score 0):

You can query into a destination table with a single command:

```
bigquery = Google::Cloud::Bigquery.new(...)
dataset = bigquery.dataset('my_dataset')
job = bigquery.query_job("SELECT * FROM source_table", table: dataset.table('destination_table'), write: 'truncate', create: 'needed')
job.wait_until_done!
```

From http://www.rubydoc.info/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-ruby/Gcloud%2FBigquery%2FProject%3Aquery_job